# Image rotation Protactor UI

Tags: ios, iphone, swift, user-interface, image-rotation

I am planning to create an image rotation UI like apple [image: Rotation UI]

Need an idea how can I implement this or if anyone can help me with any open source or apple API for this.

Comment: check my answer and let me know if you have any issue.

Comment: probably best to subclass UIControl so that you can react to all typical ui event like touchesBegan, etc.

Answer (score 1):

you can use this:

```
//rotate 45 degrees
imgView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (.pi / 4))

//rotate 90 degrees
imgView.transform = CGAffineTransform(rotationAngle: (.pi / 2))
```

and so on as per your requirement, calculate and transform image on every event...